# Вставка одного значения во все строки одного столбца mySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть уже заполненная БД появилась необходимость добавить в нее новый столбец. Как всем уже существующим записям присвоить в этот новый столбец значение "Есть в наличии"??? Можно ли это сделать на прямую, через интерфейс phpMyadmin? Или только через php код INSERT INTO?

Comment: и при чем тут  пхп? добавьте столбец, выполните тут же update запрос. insert into тут вообще при чем?

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Comment: я всегда считал, что update без параметров хорошо знаком  всем начинающим SQL писателям. :)

Comment: При создании столбца укажите требуемое значение как дефолтное - оно будет присвоено всем существующим записям. UPDATE нафиг не нужен.